# Can't connect to IBM MQ via Client Connection type channel

Tags: .net-core, ibm-mq

On my dev instance of IBM MQ Server have been created two channels "DEV.APP.SVRCONN" and "CLIENT.DEF.CLNCONN". First one is "Server-connection" type and second "Client-Connection". I use .net core and assembly "amqmdnetstd.dll" to get the messages from the queue. Via server-connection channel I can do that. But use via client-connection channel, I can't event get connected just receive an error like below:

```
MQException caught: 2059 - MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE
at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager.Connect(String queueManagerName)
```

Please, help me to identify the reason of error. Thanks.

Comment: A SVRCONN channel is defined on the queue manager.  The CLNTCONN channel when defined on the queue manager or via "runmqsc -n" will be added to a CCDT file for a client to use.  You have to tell the client how to find the CCDT in various ways.  A client can also specify the connection details directly programatically.  In any event, you would never connect to a CLNTCONN channel, this is just the client half of a SVRCONN channel when the client uses a CCDT.  In a CCDT setup the CLNTCONN will have the same name as the SVRCONN.

Comment: @JoshMc - you should make this into an answer?

Comment: @JoshMc thank you for explanation. It works perfectly without ssl. Now, I am trying to configure ssl and faced with another problem. Could please help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55750632/cant-connect-to-ibm-mq-channel-from-net-core-client