# Can't connect to IBM MQ Channel from .net core client

Tags: .net-core, ibm-mq

I have configured ssl for queue manager name "QMA" and channel named "QMACLCHL". Just set certificate label and chipher name. For queue manager also set the key store path (default value). In that directory generated .kbd file and stashed password file. By commands like these:

```
cd /var/mqm/qmgrs/QMA/ssl
runmqakm -keydb -create -db key.kdb -pw ********* -stash
runmqakm -cert -create -db key.kdb -label certqma -stashed -size 2048 -sigalg SHA512WithRSA -dn CN=QMA
runmqakm -cert -extract -db key.kdb -label certqma -file qma.arm -stashed
runmqakm -cert -add -db key.kdb -lable "QMA" -file /var/mqm/qmgrs/QMA/ssl/qma.arm -format ascii -stashed
```

Then copied these file on another PC and try to connect to queue manager over SSL.  My .net code looks like this:

```
Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
properties.Add(MQC.MQCA_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY, "E:\\workspace ttttt\\test_projects\\IBMMQ\\Receiver\\ssl\\key");
properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, "E:\\workspace ttttt\\test_projects\\IBMMQ\\Receiver\\ssl"); ;
properties.Add(MQC.MQCACH_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");


properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");//TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
properties.Add(MQC.MQCACH_SSL_PEER_NAME, "net_client");
properties.Add(MQC.SSL_RESET_COUNT_PROPERTY, 400000);
properties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "mqm");
properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "172.19.165.167");
properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "QMACLCHL");
properties.Add(MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY, "172.19.165.167(1414)");

// create connection
Console.Write("Connecting to queue manager.. ");
MQEnvironment.SSLCertRevocationCheck = false;
//MQEnvironment.SSLCipherSpec = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256";
MQEnvironment.CertificateLabel = "certqma";

queueManager = new MQQueueManager("QMA", properties);
```

Also I configured environment variables (MQCHLLIB, MQCHLTAB) for tab configuration file. Code above generate trace like below and enven doesn't try to connect:

```
Remote Address:172.19.165.167:1414
000001BC 19:37:21.374097   11208.4     Local Address:0.0.0.0:0
000001BD 19:37:21.374139   11208.4     Bind
000001BE 19:37:21.380208   11208.4     Bind returned 0.0.0.0:17040
000001BF 19:37:21.380256   11208.4     Connect
000001C0 19:37:21.382369   11208.4     Connect returned True
000001C1 19:37:21.383946   11208.4     TCP/IP LINGER disabled
000001C2 19:37:21.383997   11208.4     Using socket send buffer size 32768
000001C3 19:37:21.384409   11208.4     Using socket receive buffer size 32768
000001C4 19:37:21.384450   11208.4    -----------}  MQTCPConnection.ConnectUsingLocalAddr(ParsedLocalAddr,IPAddress,int) rc=OK
000001C5 19:37:21.384959   11208.4     Constructing IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQEncryptedSocket#004CACA0 MQMBID sn=p912-L190313.DE su=_FGqKtkWOEemwVcDgaesw_A pn=basedotnet/nmqi/NmqiObject.cs
000001C6 19:37:21.384986   11208.4     Constructing IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQEncryptedSocket#004CACA0 MQMBID sn=p912-L190313.DE su=_FGqKtkWOEemwVcDgaesw_A pn=basedotnet/nmqi/MQEncryptedSocket_s.cs
000001C7 19:37:21.386449   11208.4    -----------{  MQEncryptedSocket.RetrieveAndValidateSSLParams(MQConnectOptions)
000001C8 19:37:21.387062   11208.4     IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQEncryptedSocket#004CACA0 throwing MQException: cc=2 rc=2381
000001C9 19:37:21.388522   11208.4     New MQException CompCode: 2 Reason: 2381
000001CA 19:37:21.399370   11208.4    -----------}! MQEncryptedSocket.RetrieveAndValidateSSLParams(MQConnectOptions) rc=(Unknown(2381))
000001CB 19:37:21.401318   11208.4     CompCode: 2, Reason: 2381
000001CC 19:37:21.401693   11208.4     New MQException CompCode: 2 Reason: 2538
000001CD 19:37:21.405884   11208.4    -----------{  ManagedCommonServices.GetMessage(string objectId,uint returncode,uint control,out string basicmessage,out string extendedmessage,out string replymessage,MQLONG basicLength,MQLONG
```

When I removed property **MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY**, app try to connect to server but server reject the connection with error:

```
AMQ9639E: Remote channel 'QMACLCHL' did not specify a CipherSpec.

EXPLANATION:
Remote channel 'QMACLCHL' did not specify a CipherSpec when the local channel
expected one to be specified.
```

I don't understand what I am doint wrong. Please, help me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you running in Managed or Unmanaged mode?

Comment: Sorry I missed one line. Yes, I use managed mode. properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);

Comment: If you are using managed mode, then you can't use GSKit based KDB files and you can't use the CCDT. Read this:- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q120370_.htm

Comment: @MoragHughson understand kdb not used for managed, but why is CCDT not an option, I thought managed can use CCDT with out an issue?

Comment: @JoshMc - I thought managed could not use any external files, and CCDT is an external file. Happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: Based on this article https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q120610_.htm. IBM MQ.NET only supports Client Channel Definition Tables (.TAB files) that are on a local computer. Could you please advice me key storage type, if .kbd is not supported?

Comment: Nazar, as mentioned by Morag you can not use a `kdb` file with Manged mode.  I noted in prior question you were using `amqmdnetstd.dll` which can only be used in Managed mode.  Manged mode uses windows key store.

Comment: @MoragHughson, I have used CCDT with Managed mode and it works fine, in fact this page even shows it is supported for Managed .NET: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q130380_.htm.  Also from PMR I have open where for XMS it was communicated and doc update is pending that XMSC.WMQ_CCDTURL is supported only for Managed mode XMS.NET.

Comment: Nazar, to specify the managed mode key store location you would use something like `properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, "*SYSTEM");` or `*USER`.  If you need a private cert then that cert needs to be added at the windows level.

Comment: Here is a answer that discusses the windows cert store details as it related to Managed .NET "[IBM MQ.Net CertificateLabel, CipherSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347768/ibm-mq-net-certificatelabel-cipherspec/42348037#42348037)".  Also note that .NET will not negotiate the ciphserspec that you specify in the program, it is used only to determine the protocol to use (ex: TLS1.2), the cipher will be based on the windows policy and negotiate to the highest cipher available between MQ server and windows policy.  This is key since on MQ side `SSLCIPH` needs to match what is negotiated.

Comment: @JoshMc I have made all changes as you recommend. But now I faces with problem like this:  

Client callback has been invoked to find client certificate
Client callback has been invoked to find client certificate
Use the first certificate that is from an acceptable issuer.
SSL Server Certificate validation failed - RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: Please edit and add the details to the question.  Is that a client side error?

Comment: @JoshMc My client app can't validate server certificate. I use the same self singned cert on both sides. My question how to disable cert validation? Because now I receive an error like this : "System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure." Thanks.

Comment: Did you import both the private and signed public key.